Elastic Search distinct result
I have this query that searches for all records with errors but I want to have only the results for each jobid
Elasticsearch Query DSL
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "level": "ERROR"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "unique_jobs": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "metadata.CSBJobId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

this is the error
"[match_phrase] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]"


The error reason is hierarchy of query and aggs is wrong. Try like the following.
It should look like the following:
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {...},
  "aggs": {...}
}


GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "level": "ERROR"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_jobs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "metadata.CSBJobId"
      }
    }
  }
}


